# yum + Multilib version problems found

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

we are installing now docker on rhel 7.2 version

during yum install we see the following

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:   found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libsepol which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libsepol of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libsepol.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libsepol installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libsepol installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.i686 != libsepol-2.5-10.el7.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libselinux-2.5-15.el7.x86_64 != libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.i686
```

is its mean that we can remove safety the rpm's - `libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.i686 and libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.i686`

in order to resolve the problem we install the following additional rpm's

```
libselinux-2.5-15.el7.i686.rpm 
libsepol-2.5-10.el7.i686.rpm
```

**but now we get**

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libselinux-devel-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@local)
           Requires: libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Removing: libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)
               libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Updated By: libselinux-2.5-15.el7.x86_64 (/libselinux-2.5-15.el7.x86_64)
               libselinux = 2.5-15.el7
Error: Package: libsepol-devel-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64 (@local)
           Requires: libsepol = 2.1.9-3.el7
           Removing: libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)
               libsepol = 2.1.9-3.el7
           Updated By: libsepol-2.5-10.el7.x86_64 (/libsepol-2.5-10.el7.x86_64)
               libsepol = 2.5-10.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the probl
```

Comment: What is the reason for keeping on rhel 7.2 which is a few years old. You should consider a global update (yum update) to restore a consistent and up-to-date system.